# What's wrong with my pointers (open_stackdumpfile error)?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been attempting to write code for a basic string reversal. There seems to be some basic pointer issue with the following code as it gives the following error, but I can't figure it out:

**1 [main] reversestring 9748 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to reversestring.exe.stackdump RUN FAILED (exit value 35,584, total time: 216ms)**

I've included commented code just for the program to make sense. The error occurs when the code is executed with the comments.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char *myString = "Hello World!";
    char temp;

    int len = strlen(myString);

    char * strPtr = myString;
    char * endPtr = myString + len-1;

   //while (strPtr < endPtr){
        temp=*endPtr;    
        //*endPtr=*strPtr;
       *strPtr=temp;
       // strPtr++;
      //  endPtr--;
   //}

  //  cout << myString; 


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olaf: what makes this C++ code and not C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do: `char *myString = "Hello World!";` you are assigning a *constant string* to `myString`, and a constant string can't be modified.

You can do:

```
char myString[] = "Hello World!";
```

This will allocate a string that is sufficiently large to contain "hello world!" and then the compiler copies that string into your string. That string can now be modified.